# How to create mongo schema with first name of field using character '$' dollar sign in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, schema, dollar-sign

I want to send data to mongo and an api endpoint from nodejs. The json format that used by another api is like below :

```
{
    "$type" : "$create_account",
    "$api_key" : "a167abc7760c6dc3",
    "$user_id" : "INSERT_USER_ID",
    "$user_email" : "acapone@gmail.com",
    "$time" : 1352329200,
    // Supported Fields Examples
    "$name" : "Al Capone",
    "$phone" : "1-415-555-6040",
    "$social_sign_on_type" : "$twitter",
    // Custom Fields
    "twitter_handle" : "AlCaps"
}
```

And i created the mongo schema like below :

```
{
    $type : String,
    $api_key : String
    $user_id : String,
    $user_email : String,
    $time : Number,
    // Supported Fields Examples
    $name : String,
    $phone : String,
    $social_sign_on_type : String,
    // Custom Fields
    $twitter_handle : String
}
```

But when i running my apps to send data to mongo and api endpoint, it's raise up an error. And the error is :

```
key $type must not start with '$'
```

it's seems mean that i can't start the name of parameter with dollar sign, is dollar sign can be use in javascript as the first latter in the name of variable?

can somebody help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your field name in mongoDb can't start with $ sign. Refer the link below

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/